# Unable to get Image Src with Javascript in Android Browser

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having some issues with getting img src in javascript.
Javascript:
My code is as follows

```
function getSrc()
{
var testImg = qrCodeDiv.getElementsByTagName('testImg');
alert(testImg.src);
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="./images/payment/1.jpg" id="testImg">A Random Image</a>
```

The function is called on click. testImg.src returns undefined in Android.
The code works fine on PC.
I looked around, did'nt find any other topics that were similar.

Please help.

Comment: "_The code works fine on PC_" It certainly doesn't, `getElementsByTagName` searches elements with the passed tag name, and returns a HTMLCollection of the found elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `getElementById`. `getElementsByTagName` takes a tag name like `img`